# Obout Tree .HTML method giving timeout error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, obout

We have used Obout Tree View in our application. Problem is that it works totally fine on our development server but its .HTML property is getting timed out on the client's staging server. I have checked dll version's and they are same. Also tried replacing Obout's dll on staging server as well.

Code where it gives error

```
UserGroupsSelection.Text = userGroups.HTML.Replace("<img alt="""" src=""/cfr/Tree/" & DBSystem.Values.StaticFileVersion & "/Icons//"" />", String.Empty)
```

Where UserGroups is obout_ASPTreeView_2_NET.Tree
It's getting Timeout at userGroups.HTML .
I could not find anything else on why it's working on our development environment and not on client's staging.

Could it be a Staging environment issue? Kindly suggest me on the same.

PS- It's My first question on Stackoverflow so please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: On the development system are you display the same data? the same number of nodes and items? Are you using a licenced copy or a free version?. For instance the free Obout grid will only handle 100 records - any more and the grid will not display at all.

Comment: Hi Mych , Sorry for late reply, No the data is different on development than on Staging. Staging has hell lot of data and larger number of nodes, and I guess more than 100 records. And yes we are using licensed version. I am just checking on staging if it works with 100 records or not and will update you.

Comment: Ashish... If its a licenced copy then there will be no restrictions. It's only the free copies that have them as they are meant for review or small scale apps. The 100 records refers to the obout grid as this was one of the controls I used from the Obout suite. Unfortunately I have not used their treeview.

Comment: Hey Mych, Thanks for the Head Start, issue was with nodes only, although I could load upto 30000 of them after that it become slower and then loading more nodes causing it to time out. So I will need to restrict loading nodes beyond that. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problems.... check if there is a way to load on demand... I use Telerik controls now and they have this facility

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer to anyone who might run into same problem.

We have changed the UI to search for user groups and add them instead of loading them into obout tree and allowing users to select them, since obout tree was failing to load more than 30000 - 40000 nodes and the UI was becoming unresponsive.